# Making C++ DLL for C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have made a very simple Dll like this:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) int Try(int v)
  {
    return 10 + v;
  }
}
```

Then I want to use it in my C# app:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
    public static extern int Try(int v);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wynik: " + Try(20));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It was working until I have tried to pas parameter. Now I have following error at runtime:

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'ConsoleApplication2!ConsoleApplication1.Program::Try' has unbalanced
>   the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does
>   not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling
>   convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

I have no idea where is the problem.

Comment: Make it `int __stdcall Try(int v)` in your C++ code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you've got contains a good advice indeed:

> Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

You should have the same calling convention specified on both sides (C++ dll and C# assembly). In C++ you can specify it by prepending function declaration with one of __cdecl, __stdcall, etc.

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Try(int v)
  {
    return 10 + v;
  }
}
```

On the C# side you specify it with DllImport attribute, the default one is CallingConvention.StdCall which corresponds to __stdcall in C++, so, it looks like you have a __cdecl on the C++ side. To fix the issue either use __stdcall in your DLL as shown above, or use CDecl in C# like this:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Try(int v);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wynik: " + Try(20));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm just beginning my learning about DLL's and using it in C#. I wanted just a simple working code to begin with. Thank you again for great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The default calling convention in C and C++ is `__cdecl`; the default calling convention used by .NET P/Invoke is `__stdcall` -- you need to reconcile these two.

- Either make your native function `__stdcall`, as Hans suggested:

  ```
  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Try(int v)
  ```
- Or make your managed P/Invoke signature use `__cdecl`:

  ```
  [DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern int Try(int v);
  ```