# How should I specify the P/invoke interface for this code?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

In C++ I have some code that requires a `const char *` to be passed in:

```
void Load(const char *filename)
```

If I try using `String` as MSDN seems to suggest:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll")]
protected static extern void Load(String filename);
```

I end up getting an exception stating that the call has an unbalanced stack, due to a mismatch between the managed P/Invoke call and the actual C++ function signature.

What would be the appropriate C# function signature I would need to use? I've tried googling for the answer but I'm not coming up with anything.

---

**The solution:** It turns out that the reason why I was getting an "unbalanced stack" error was because the test code I was running called for a file that didn't actually exist in the directory. With `CallingConvention=cdecl`, and the file in the appropriate place, the issue was resolved.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666144/making-c-dll-for-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the calling convention. And while we're at it, you probably need to specify the character set since it may assume Unicode otherwise:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
protected static extern void Load(String filename);
```

Comment: The `CallingConvention` doesn't make much sense to me, since I have some other declarations that are importing fine and don't require the Cdecl. Why would this require it? I'll try the `CharSet.Ansi` though.

Comment: What are the other ones? Standard windows functions are stdcall [the default], but functions you make in C++ are likely cdecl.

Comment: All the functions I'm importing are declared as `Cdecl`. This is the only one that's been problematic due to the `const char *` parameter.

Comment: D'oh. It turns out when I was calling the function, it was trying to open a file that didn't exist. I still had to add the `Cdecl` call convention to the code though.

Comment: Default CharSet is Ansi. That's superfluous. Calling convention is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the [`MarshalAsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) like e.g.

```
[DllImport("foo.dll")]
protected static extern void Load(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string filename);
```

You can pass one of the [`UnmanagedType` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) values to the `MarshalAsAttribute` constructor.

See also [this overview article over at Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/essentialpinvoke.aspx).

Comment: @UweKim: I tried this and I still receive the same error message.