# Wrap native DLL for C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, pinvoke

I wrote a C++ DLL and now I need to call a native function from a managed app.

The exported native function appears like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
bool NativeMethod(char *param1, char *param2, char *result);
```

So, from C# I'll call that function passing 2 input params, 1 output param and obviously I'll read the return bool value.

I tried to wrap all this in many ways, but always I get a `PInvokeStackImbalance` exception.
The only way I know to call native function is by applying `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`) on .NET function declaration. However in this way I'm not able to read the output param (it's empty string always) and also the return value is always true.

Comment: what import have u tried?

Comment: I tried something like: [DllImport("MyDll", EntryPoint = "NativeMethod")]
 public static extern Boolean NativeMethod(string param1, string param2, string param3);

Also with out param3 or StringBuilder or MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]

Comment: You realize that this output parameter won't work, right? C# strings are **immutable**.

Comment: [DllImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "NativeMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern bool NativeMethod(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string param1,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string param2,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string param3); - chk my answer!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, I'd adjust the prototype of your native function.

Since this function has a *C interface*, you should use a C type for booleans, not a C++ type like `bool`. You may want to use Win32's `BOOL` type.

Moreover, as it currently is, your function is prone to *buffer overruns*: it's better to add another parameter to specify the maximum size of the destination `result` string buffer.

Note also that a widespread *calling convention* for DLLs exporting pure C interface functions (like lots of Win32 API functions) is `__stdcall` (not `__cdecl`). I'd use that as well.

Last, since the first two parameters are *input* strings, you may want to use `const` to make it clear and enforce const-correctness.

So, I'd make the prototype of the exported native function like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
BOOL __stdcall NativeFunction(
    const char *in1, 
    const char *in2, 
    char *result, 
    int resultMaxSize);
```

Then, on the C# side, you can use the following P/Invoke:

```
   [DllImport(
        "NativeDll.dll", 
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool NativeFunction(
        string in1,
        string in2,
        StringBuilder result, 
        int resultMaxSize);
```

Note that for the output string, a `StringBuilder` is used.

Note also that `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` is used to marshal C#'s Unicode UTF-16 strings to ANSI (pay attention to the fact that the conversion is *lossy* - if you want a non-lossy conversion, just use `wchar_t*` strings on the C++ side as well).

I did a test with a simple C++ native DLL:

```
// NativeDll.cpp

#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
BOOL __stdcall NativeFunction(
    const char *in1, 
    const char *in2, 
    char *result, 
    int resultMaxSize)
{
    // Parameter check
    if (in1 == nullptr 
        || in2 == nullptr 
        || result == nullptr 
        || resultMaxSize <= 0)
        return FALSE;

    // result = in1 + in2
    strcpy_s(result, resultMaxSize, in1);
    strcat_s(result, resultMaxSize, in2);

    // All right
    return TRUE;
}
```

And it is called successfully by the following C# console app code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharpClient
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(
            "NativeDll.dll", 
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool NativeFunction(
            string in1,
            string in2,
            StringBuilder result, 
            int resultMaxSize);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder(200);
            if (! NativeFunction("Hello", " world!", result, result.Capacity))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error.");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll save yourself a lot of P/Invoke headaches if you just use COM Interop instead. Put the method in a COM interface and change the signature to follow COM conventions:

```
interface ISomeInterface : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT NativeMethod([in] BSTR bstrParam1, [in] BSTR bstrParam2, 
                         [out] BSTR* pbstrParam3, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pvbResult);
}
```

I changed **char*** to **BSTR** and **bool** to **VARIANT_BOOL** because those are the types used by COM for strings and bools, respectively. Also, all COM methods must return an **HRESULT**. If you want an "actual" return value you have to add it as the last **out** parameter and also mark it with the **retval** attribute.

Then add a reference to the COM component from the C# project and you'll get an intuitive C# signature without having to guess how to match C++ types with C# types:

```
bool NativeMethod(string bstrParam1, string bstrParam2, out string pbstrParam3)
```

(That's how it appears in Object Browser.)

Comment: I agree with you that COM offers convenience and simplicity to C# clients (in fact, I gave your answer a +1 vote). However, _building_ the COM server in C++ with ATL does have a learning curve if compared to just exporting pure-C-interface functions from native DLLs. If the OP can build COM components in C++, then I agree it's a good suggestion. But if he can't, probably it's better trying to write a proper P/Invoke for the native C-interface DLL.

Comment: +1 For serious work between the CLR and native code on the same machine, COM is the way to go. But overkill if you're only trying to call one thing.

Answer (score 1):

why note using .Net code marshalling using DLLImport such as the following

```
[DllImport(@"C:\TestLib.dll")]
        public static extern void ProtectDocument(
            out [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string validToDate);
```

and then you can call the function as local function as the following

```
string x=string.empty;
ProtectDocument(out x);
```

Comment: DLL Import is just what I'm using but I'm getting the above mentionated exception. Also, how can I declare the third param that I want use as "out" type?

Comment: you can use out onfront of the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DllImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "NativeMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern bool NativeMethod(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string param1,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string param2,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string param3);
```

Replace `LPStr` with `LPWStr` if you're working with wide chars.

Comment: hi, could you explain what a wide char is?

Answer (score -1):

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "NativeMethod")]
public static unsafe extern bool NativeMethod(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string param1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string param2,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] char *param3);
```

The output parameter has to be a `char *`, since C# strings are immutable. You call the method (in an unsafe context) like this:

```
char[] output = new char[100];
fixed (char *param = &output[0])
{
    NativeMethod("blahblah", "blahblah", param);
}
```

Unless the output parameter is not a string but only a single character, in which case you can just do this:

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "NativeMethod")]
public static unsafe extern bool NativeMethod(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string param1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string param2,
    out char param3);
```

And you can just use it like this:

```
char output;
NativeMethod("blahblah", "blahblah", out output);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I still get exception.

Comment: @AppDeveloper He specified. Read the question.

Comment: Nothing works. I' m forced to use CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl option, else nothing works, however I never achieve the right return value (it's always true).

Comment: @bit Have you tried `int` as the return value instead of `bool`?

Comment: No, I didn't. However this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666144/making-c-dll-for-c-sharp) helped me to understand why I forced to use cdecl option. Ok, I'll try with int type as return value, however I would be able to pass third param as "out" in order to read some native message.. but it seems to ignore any changed on native code..

Comment: Ther's something to strange..I changed return value with int. The native function alway reurn 0 or 1, but by .NET code I get something like 123402??!!

Comment: Ok, I've made some adjustment. I return an int value, I pass two input value but I removed the third param (means as out) because I cannot get any result when function returns. I think I need to know many other stuff before deeping in question such as passing string to c++ functions.

Comment: @bit I don't know mate. What's in the C++ function?

Comment: ?? Please see the first post: bool NativeMethod(char *param1, char *param2, char *result)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23861/discussion-between-antonijn-and-bit)