# Unity how to use native dll or convert to managed

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, native

I am trying to use a native c++ UWP component in a unity project for hololens.

I have successfully used a managed dll, but I can;t figure out how to use this native dll/

I want to either convert the dll to a managed dll or find some way to use a native dll.

Comment: Are you trying to use the dll in .Net Project ? If so, an Interopability for the dll will be generated automatically .. we call its CCW - Com Callable Wrapper..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this: [Wrap native DLL for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673049/wrap-native-dll-for-c-sharp) (the 2nd code block is interesting)?

Converting the dll is not possible afaik. You can convert the c++ code into c# and then create a managed dll but importing a native dll would be easier.

EDIT: Should mention that i don't mean the question in particular, just the 2nd code block, where the dll gets imported.

Answer (score 0):

Memory management works completely different in C++ so it is not possible to use a C++ library direclty in C#.

C++ uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C.2B.2B) for encoding method signatures and this name mangling is not standardized (meaning it depends on the compiler).
To solve this you require to export them in an extern "C" section using a static "std call".

This means you need to create a wrapper with static methods for each instance method used in C#.

From [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//NativePlugins.html) (note that importing dll is different for ios, as shown in the code below)

```cs
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour {

       #if UNITY_IPHONE

       // On iOS plugins are statically linked into
       // the executable, so we have to use __Internal as the
       // library name.
       [DllImport ("__Internal")]

       #else

       // Other platforms load plugins dynamically, so pass the name
       // of the plugin's dynamic library.
       [DllImport ("PluginName")]

       #endif

       private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();

       void Awake () {
          // Calls the FooPluginFunction inside the plugin
          // And prints 5 to the console
          print (FooPluginFunction ());
       }
    }
```

You might also read this [Unity Answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1200157/nonstatic-extern-functions-from-dll-plugin-import.html), for further info.