# GDI Win32 Plotting Graphs

Tags: c++, winapi, plot, gdi

In my small, small and humble c++ Win32 GUI application, I got to the point of being able to draw a grid :

[image]

This is in preparation for displaying spectral data, the 36 (floats) measurement points returned from my device. I still have to get the axis labeled... This is my code for drawing the grid so far :

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);    

    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, HBRUSH (COLOR_WINDOW + 1));  

    bool Retour;
    
    pen = (HPEN)GetStockObject(TRANSPARENT);
    SelectObject(hdc, pen);

    Brosse = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(240, 240, 240));
    SelectObject(hdc, Brosse);

    Retour = LineTo(hdc, 100, 500);*/

    Retour = Rectangle(hdc, 350, 150, 750, 375);

    for (int i = 380; i <= 730; i=i+10) {   // 36 vertical lines
        MoveToEx(hdc, i, 175, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, i, 350);
    }
    for (int i = 175; i <= 350; i = i + 17) {
        MoveToEx(hdc, 375, i, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, 730, i);
    }

    DeleteObject(pen);
    DeleteObject(Brosse);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

As you can see, I located the code to draw the grid inside the WM_PAINT procedure. It made sense to locate the code there to experiment with GDI instructions but also because the grid needs to be visible at launch time as part of the interface.

My question is how should I go "updating" the graph when, after pressing the "Measure Sample" button, I have access to the data? I gather that the code to draw on the grid does not necessarily needs to be located inside the WM_PAINT procedure, does it? According to my limited understanding, as long as I can get a Device Context handle (hDC), I should be good to go? All I need to plot is a "line" uniting the 36 data points from left to right. Not sure I should use simple MOVE_TO and LINE_TO for this purpose? I think there is a way to draw a "smoothed" line that passes through all 36 data points?

One last thing, if I may... I'm going at this in a very elementary way because I'm intimidated by the idea of using a "graphic library" and objects. But I suspect they would make my life a lot easier while offering umpteen options that will take me too long to figure out, I'll bet, and implement?

Thank you so much in advance for your kind help and patience.

Comment: `SelectObject` transfers ownership of resources. The resource selected into the device context is owned by the DC, with the object previously selected into the DC is now your responsibility. With that, it's always a mistake to delete an object while it is still selected into a DC. The most common pattern here is: `1` Select object into DC, `2` use the object, `3` select the object back out of (by selecting the previous object into) the DC, `4` clean up your resources. Also make sure to read [WM_PAINT message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint).

Comment: Quite unrelated to this issue, you might want to see [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview). It doesn't involve writing any code, but will make your next screenshot look distinctly different. Unarguably better, too.

Answer (score 2):

You should always do all your drawing in your `WM_PAINT` handler.  That way, the window will redraw correctly when something that was covering it is removed, for example.

When your graph data changes, call [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) to prompt a redraw.

To determine what to redraw, you will need to pass suitable variables to your `WM_PAINT` handler.  Start with `MoveTo` and `LineTo` (or `Polyline` or `PolyPolyline`) and get that working first.  You can then investigate smoothing algorithms if you think you need them.

Comment: The "Smoothing" is the cherry on the icing. I'll promise I'll stick with doing my painting from within WM_PAINT. Initially, there is no data to plot, so I have to use some kind of "flag" to control which codes executes: the empty graph alone or the graph plus the "line" for the device data? So, I guess I need to set this flag from inside the Measure button "event" so that, once I have the data, I call InvalidateRect() to cause the graph to "update" using the device data while having set that flag accordingly? Would that be a good approach?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, yes.

Comment: For the purpose of "development", I decide to use "dummy" data. So when the application launches, it should have some data "to chew on". We'll see where that leads me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need a flag to distinguish between *"data available"* and *"no data available"*. Simply store your data in a container. A container with size 0 indicates no data.

Answer (score 0):

You should place all of your custom painting code in the WM_PAINT handler of the window, yes. You can call a separate function for painting the graph if you like. Pass it the HDC you get from `BeginPaint(...)` and your spectral data. However, that function needs to be called from the WM_PAINT handler.

If you handle painting in WM_PAINT then to update the graph when the data changes you would call `InvalidateRect(...)` on the window. `InvalidateRect` tells Windows essentially "this window has changed and needs to be repainted". It will drive a call to the paint handler.

One problem you are going to run into is that your graph is going to flicker. It may not be too noticeable. It may not bother you, but the problem is that in each call to the WM_PAINT handler you are erasing the graph in the screen device context; this erasure will be visible. A solution to this problem would be to "double-buffer" the graph: create an offscreen bitmap, paint into that when data changes, and paint the offscreen bitmap to the screen in WM_PAINT. You could also make the graph a separate child window that manages the offscreen bitmap, etc., if you are ever going to need multiple graphs or just to add some modularity to the code.

As for whether you'd have an easier time with a graphics library ... possibly, but more to the point: you would have an easier time using a higher level GUI library than the Win32 API. If you only care about Windows, consider the .Net frameworks WinForms or WPF. Otherwise, consider Qt.

Comment: Thanks for the invaluable and detailed suggestions. I wish I could use .NET but I'm stuck with an SDK DLL that uses too complex calls for me to "port" them to either c# or vb. I tried QT and would FAR prefer to work in QT *but* I'm limited by the Qlibrary object and my Resolve DLL functions which I have only been to use from within MS C++ (using LoadLibrary). I realize I will see a "flicker" when the graph is "invalidated". My plan is to get the logic working "with the flicker effect" and, later, if it really bothers me, I'll investigate the "double-buffering" technique :-)

Comment: Could you call the DLL via "P/Invoking" in .Net? i.e.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673049/wrap-native-dll-for-c-sharp

Comment: I don't see why not. But, in terms of "learning how to interface effectively with the device", I chose the c++ route because the sample application provided by the device manufacturer was written in c++. But since I did not know much c++, it would have made sense to use P/Invoking, I agree 100%.

Comment: Windows Forms is a managed (and craptastic) wrapper around the native Windows controls. It is not a replacement strategy for native code. Even less so WPF, which both invented its own UI stack and provides a managed API only. That's not a replacement strategy for anything, unless your goal is complete vendor lock-in. WinUI, on the other hand, contains the standard UI implementation for Windows 10, written in native code, with a native API. Now **that** is a true replacement strategy for native code.